# Netlogo How to avoid NOBODY Runtime error?

Tags: runtime, netlogo

How can I avoid NOBODY Runtime error? The following is sample code. This is a code that can be used for zero division error avoidance. Therefore, I know that it can not be used to avoid NOBODY error. But I can not find any other way. The following is a Runtime error message-> "IFELSE-VALUE expected input to be a TRUE / FALSE but got NOBODY instead." I appreciate your advice.

```
  set top ifelse-value (nobody)
  [ 0 ][ top ]
  set ts turtles with [speed = 0 and not right-end] 
  set top max-one-of turtles [who]
  set topx [xcor] of top ; A NOBODY error appears in "of" of this code
  set L count ts with [xcor > topx]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input of `ifelse-value` needs to be a reporter the returns either `true` or `false` (full details [here](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/ifelse-value.html). So, if you use `nobody` as the input, Netlogo does not evaluate whether or not the input is `nobody` or not, it just reads `nobody`- in other words your input is **not** returning either `true` or `false`.

For input, then, you need to instead use a boolean variable (one that is either `true` or `false`), a `to-report` that returns `true` or `false`, an expression that Netlogo can evaluate, etc. Consider the following examples:

```
to go

  let x true
  set top ifelse-value ( x ) 
  ["x is true"] 
  ["x is NOT true"]
  print ( word "Example 1:  " top )

  set top ifelse-value ( this-is-true ) 
  ["Reporter returned true"] 
  ["Reporter did not return true"]
  print ( word "Example 2:  " top )

  set x nobody
  set top ifelse-value ( x = nobody ) 
  ["x IS nobody"] 
  ["Is NOT nobody"]
  print ( word "Example 3:  " top )

  set x 0
  set top ifelse-value ( x = nobody ) 
  ["x IS nobody"] 
  ["x Is NOT nobody"]
  print ( word "Example 4:  " top )

  set top ifelse-value ( nobody = nobody ) 
  ["nobody = nobody"] 
  ["nobody != nobody"]
  print ( word "Example 5:  " top )

end

to-report this-is-true
  report true
end
```